# Headers to connect xtrinsic sensor board

Tags: sensor

I have both (pi and board) as illustrated [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/06/farnell-xtrinsic-mems-sensor-board-for-raspberry-pi/).

However, both boards have pins. Neither have the female ends for the connection. What kind of headers do i need? Are there female - female available? I haven't seen any at adafruit or sparkfun.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at a GPIO socket connector like [this](https://www.modmypi.com/gpio-socket-connector-to-female-jumper-sockets).